# Сервис закрывается при закрытии приложения

Tags: android, android-service

Я знаю что есть уже много вопросов на эту тему, но мне ничего не помогло. Метод onStartCommand возвращает Service.START_STICKY, выполнял тот же код в startForegroundService, сервис держится максимум 15 секунд после закрытия приложения и все. startForeground мне не подходит, т.к. это чат и постоянно висящее уведомление здесь не подходит. У AndroidManifest уже есть
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`, вот объявление сервиса в манифесте:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
```

Может еще причина в том что я вызываю сервис у onDestroy методе активити, может надо по другому как-то?!

Код вызова сервиса:

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Код самого сервиса:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public ComponentName startForegroundService(Intent service) {
    // тот самый код что и в onStartCommand
    return super.startForegroundService(service);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    first = true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Остановлено!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // мой код
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

}

Comment: Может хотя бы код сервиса прикрепишь?)

Answer (score 0):

Foreground Service – это сервис, о котором пользователь осведомлен. Поесть висящее уведомление необходимо. Вам нужно дополнительно вызвать `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)`, для этого. К сожалению, правда такова, что на сегодняшний день с текущим `minSDK = 29`, выиграть в борьбе с системой за живой сервис - сложно и совсем ни к чему. Посмотрите на JobScheduler, WorkManager. На самом деле вам не пытаются усложнить жизнь, удачи!

Comment: А как тот же Инстаграм, Телеграм работают? Они ж не делают висящее уведомление. И все приложения присылают уведомления в фоновом режиме и без висящего уведомления

Comment: @ПетроГлинський правильно, почти уверен что они используют НЕ сервис для этого, а другие инструменты, которые я попробовал вам перечислить